# ffmpeg statement for Anaglyph of Red-Cyan Color

Tags: video, ffmpeg, 3d

I'm trying to take two input videos (can be in avi, mp4, whatever ffmpeg supports) and combine them into a stereoscopic video with the "ffmpeg" utility that uses simple red and cyan colored glasses (anaglyph). I have tried the following statements with input files of type mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4  -i right.mp4          stereo3d=al:arcc  video_arcc.mp4
ffmpeg -i left.mp4  -vf "movie=right.mp4" stereo3d=al:arcc  video_arcc.avi
```

I see error messages like:

```
Error message: [NULL @ 0000000003220940] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'stereo3d=al:arcc'
stereo3d=al:arcc: Invalid argument
```

My source images are a series of JPEGs that I can convert to any input format. It would be preferrable to use left%06d.jpg" and "right%06d.jpg", but that is an extra layer of difficulty for now.

What command line options do I need for ffmpeg anaglyph red-cyan?

Answer (score 2):

`stereo3d` is a video filter so it has to be specified via a filterchain or complex. Since you have two inputs, and stereo3d only converts a single input from one form of 3D arrangement to another, you'll have to combine the two image sequences first. For which, you can use the `hstack` filter, which will place the two sequences side-by-side.

So,

```
ffmpeg -i "left%06d.jpg" -i "right%06d.jpg" -filter_complex "hstack,stereo3d=sbsl:arcc" video_arcc.mp4
```

By default, image sequences are treated as 25 FPS and hence so will the output, in this case. If the framerate is different, say 24, then the beginning will be

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i left%06d.jpg" -framerate 24 -i "right%06d.jpg
```